# Login Facebook Sdk 4.14 Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I am creating a login facebook in android using Eclipse.
My project at [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?6a55f9jql728crf)

In Android studio, It is easy to do that. But, in Eclipse, I add a Facebook lib .jar into my project. Fb .jar file is converted from facebook-android-sdk-4.14.0.aar downloaded at [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/).

Add code in manifest

> 

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

<provider
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider819134394885..."
    android:exported="true" />
```

Set up facebook

> private void setUpFacebookLogin() {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>       FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.d("Success", "Login");
        SPManager.setBooleanValue(SPManager.LOGIN_FACEBOOK, true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

}

```
Event when click on button to login
```

> LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this,
>                       Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));

When I click on login button, the app has been crashed and showed message in logcat below:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/R$layout; at com.facebook.FacebookActivity.onCreate(FacebookActivity.java:84)

Appreciate any help

Comment: Did you click Check box in project section

Comment: goto project->properties->java built path->order & export-> check this jar ?

Comment: I already checked them

Comment: Clean your project and also add aar file in libs folder too

Comment: I clean and add aar file into libs but got the same problem

Comment: I call it in 
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

Comment: please help me via skype : vudoancs

Comment: my project at https://www.mediafire.com/?6a55f9jql728crf

Comment: We aren't going to download your app. Please provide a [mcve] of the problem

Comment: And if it works in Android Studio, why use Eclipse? Are you aware that the latest version of Eclipse supports Gradle projects, so there's no reason to use JAR dependencies anymore?

Comment: please , eclipse is long gone. use android studio . this is made for a reason . and that is to make the development more easy and faster.

Comment: because my project is being built in Eclipse. Converting to Android Studio gets many errors.

Comment: Did u check that jar file in _Java Build Path_?